# What does ::pause >nul mean/do? (in batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently working on an AI in batch, I've used ::pause >nul before but I'm not exactly sure what it does. All answers are appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `::` means that the current line is a comment (it actually is an
  invalid label which works the same as a comment)
- `pause` pauses the    script untill the user presses a key
- `>nul` redirects output to    nothing.

This means that this is an outcommented pause that doesn't show `the press any key to continue . . .` message to the screen, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: No problem, always glad to help. If my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as correct by clicking the check to the left of it.

Comment: Nice answer. Moreover, you posted a helpful comment in my German question. For that, I would like to link you to the [God of Time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag/319020#319020) post for the 10 years of SO, as a thank-you gesture. This comment will selfdestruct around some time...